# Populate textboxes based on listbox selection

Tags: c#

I want to populate textboxes with data from a listbox and database table. The textboxes are getting data from a database, but it's picking only the last row of the table and not changing on listbox selection.

My code:

```
 private void agentList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string query = "Select * From tblEmployeeDetails";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        AgentId.Clear();
                        AgentId.Text = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                        FullNameTxb.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                        emailtxb.Text = reader.GetString(8);
                        winLogtxb.Text = reader.GetString(1);
                        passwordtxb.Text = reader.GetString(3);
                        dobtxb.Text = reader.GetString(6);
                        addresstxa.Text = reader.GetString(9);
                        contactNotxb.Text = reader.GetString(10);
                        niNotxb.Text = reader.GetString(11);
                        contactNotxb.Text = reader.GetString(10);
                        sortCodetxb.Text = reader.GetString(12);
                        accountNotxb.Text = reader.GetString(13);
                        startdatetxb.Text = reader.GetString(14);
                        finsishdatetxb.Text = reader.GetString(15);
                        teamcmb.Text = reader.GetString(16);
                        basicsRatetxb.Text = reader.GetDecimal(17).ToString();
                        commRatetxb.Text = reader.GetDecimal(18).ToString();
                        contracthourstxb.Text = reader.GetInt32(19).ToString();
                        mainShifttxb.Text = reader.GetString(20);
                        fridayShifttxb.Text = reader.GetString(4);
                        activecmb.Text = reader.GetBoolean(5).ToString();
                        nokNametxb.Text = reader.GetString(21);
                        nokNumtxb.Text = reader.GetString(21);
                        gendercmb.Text = reader.GetString(23);
                        empTypesmb.Text = reader.GetString(24);
                        securitycmb.Text = reader.GetString(27);
                        //mondayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(26);
                        //tuedayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(27);
                        //wendnesdayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(28);
                        //thursdayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(29);
                        //fridaydkb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(30);
                        //saturdayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(31);
                        //sundaycbk.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(32);
                        //mondayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(25); 
                        //tuedayckb.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(25);
                        //basicsRatetxb.Text = reader.GetString(16);
                        //activecmb.Text = reader.GetBoolean(15).ToString();
                        //dateTimePicker1.Value = reader.GetDateTime(5);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [SQL WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: Good god. Besides the egregiously strange/poor code, it's not very clear what you're even asking.

Comment: on list box selection text boxs data remain same its not changing on selection

Comment: 1. you are missing a filter for the rows you are returning, which I guess it's the value in the list box (i.e. query parameter for the `WHERE` clause) 2. the way you are getting the data (through a reader) + the fact that you are surprised by seeing only the last record's values in the UI, tells me that you probably want to display a grid of records (ever heard about grid controls?).

Comment: Hi Alex no i am displaying only one column of the database table and populating fields from db table fields by clicking on that list box displayed column

Comment: Alex was talking about rows not columns. Your "select * from table" which returns ALL ROWS from the table. This, paired with `ExecuteReader` and `while (reader.Read())` and one set of controls to display the data, causes your controls repeatedly read and forget previous data, and (probably) they end up with the contents of the very last row returned by the database. What you need is a precise one-row picking query, similar to `select * from table where id = 12312`. Of course, you need to provide the "id" value dynamically from the item currently selected on your listbox. Try it!

Comment: To get a visual of what is going on here, add the following `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` at the bottom of your `while` code just before the closing `}`.  This will show you that the text fields are updating with each value in the table, not just the one that you selected in your ListBox.

Comment: Hi quetzalcoatl  i have tried but its only printing same ids rows  text box not updating on next click